# How to use Symfony Lock component in different servers instance?

Tags: symfony

From the documentation of Symfony lock component
[here](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/lock.html)

I Found That

> Unlike other implementations, the Lock Component distinguishes locks instances even when they are created for the same resource. If a lock has to be used by several services, they should share the same Lock instance returned by the Factory::createLock method.

For code example

```
public function tryLock( $job):
{
    $lock = $this->factory->createLock($job->getUniqueId());
    $lock->acquire();
    return $lock->isAcquired() ;
}
```

If I run this function 2 times from other class with the same job, it will lock each other

How I can prevent this?! while I’m using this on the same server 
And the other problem is How I can use this if I use multiple  server instances

Comment: Have you looked in the store section on the exact same page your are referring to: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/lock.html#available-stores?

Comment: Ya, I already read it before, and use 2 of them redis for production and flock for local . Both are not working for the given example